# Making a table of descriptive statistics- Categorical variables not working

Tags: r, datatables

I'm in an intro Stats class and need to make a table of descriptive statistics for a project containing both categorical and quantitative variables. I just need to find n (% or mean + sd) but I have no idea how to get these values.

I've started with my first variable, Grad_Degree, and this is what I have so far:

```
SurveyFA<- read.csv("~/Downloads/SurveyFA14(1).csv",na.strings="")

SurveyWithoutMissing<-na.omit(SurveyFA)

summary(SurveyWithoutMissing)

table(SurveyWithoutMissing$Grad_Degree)
```

When I try to view a table of Grad_Degree I get:

```
< table of extent 0 >
```

I'm so confused and don't know where to go from here to get a % for this variable.

Comment: Could you show us what the dataset actually looks like? str(SurveyWithoutMissing), for a start, but ideally an example set of rows.

Comment: $ grad_degree             : Factor w/ 3 levels "no","other","pre-med": 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 ...

Comment: This is not a reproducible example.  Please check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example